# What is wrong with my while loop

Tags: python

This is a code i am working on but when i execute it , creates a problem towards the end

```
restart = "No" or "no"
while restart == "No" or "no":

    print("League Registration")
    Fristname = input("What is first name?")
    Lastname = input("What is your Last name?")
    Nickname = input("What is your nick name?")
    Eaddress = input("What is your e-mail address?")
    Skill = input("What is your skill level, E for expert or C for casual?")
    if Skill  == "C" or Skill == "c":
        print("Casual")
    elif Skill == "E" or Skill == "e":
        print("Expert")


    print (" These are your personal details:")

    print ("First Name:",Fristname)

    print("Last Name:",Lastname)

    print("Nickname:",Nickname)

    print("Email Address:",Eaddress)

    print("Skill Level:",Skill)

    Detailscon = input("Are your personal details correct: Yes or No?")

    if restart == "Yes" or "yes":
        print("Thanl you , you are now registered")
    elif restart == "No" or "no":
        print("Try again")
```

my code towards the end keeps messing up i don't know what to do

Comment: You must do `a == b or a == c` not `a == b or c`.

Comment: Note that some of your `or`s are right and some wrong - at least be *consistent*!

Comment: convert text to `lower()` and you will have to compare only with `"no"` or only with `"yes"` and you will no need `or`

Answer (score 2):

The error in your code, lies here. You see, in python

```
    while (restart == "No") or "no":
```

The operator equal will evaluate first and then check if it is true or if the string "no" is longer than zero, which it is so it will run forever.

Instead change it to.

```
    while restart in ["No", "no"]:
```

Comment: i did but when i execute the code it loops it to the beginning when i type yes which i don't want it to do

Comment: @Esh because you assing `"Yes"` to `Detailscon` and you don't change `reset` which still is `"No"`

Comment: but how do i so that ,please edit my code to help me

Comment: @Esh it is so simple that there is nothing to edit: you need `restart = input(..)` instead of `Detailscon = input(...)`